# Solve first order BVP on MATLAB

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matlab

I try to solve this equation on MATLAB
$$y^\prime(x)=x+y^2(x)\quad\forall x\in(0,0.9),\quad y(0)=1, y(0.9)=32.725$$
I write two function on matlab, on `myODE.m` file, i write

```
function result = myODE(x,y)
    result = x + (y(1)).^2;
end
```

and on `myBVP.m` file i insert this lines

```
function result = myBVP(ya, yb)
    result(1) = ya(1)-1;
    result(2) = yb(1)-32.725;
end
```

Then i initialize solver with this command

```
solinit = bvpinit(linspace(0,.9,5),[0;0]);
```

And at end i try to solve with `bvp4c` solver on MATLAB:

```
sol = bvp4c(@myODE,@myBVP,solinit);
```

But MATLAB get me this error:

```
Error using bvparguments (line 109)
Error in calling BVP4C(ODEFUN,BCFUN,SOLINIT):
  The derivative function ODEFUN should return a column vector of length 2.

Error in bvp4c (line 130)
[n,npar,nregions,atol,rtol,Nmax,xyVectorized,printstats] = ...
```

Any suggestion to correct my code or solve this on true manner?

Comment: How can a first order differential equation have two boundary conditions?

Comment: Please see: http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Boundary_value_problem @Dmoreno

Comment: That's why I'm asking you. A boundary value problem is supposed to have, at least, as many boundary conditions as the order of the differential equation. In your case, the order is 1, so one physical boundary condition has to be specified. In the case you are interested in an artificial boundary condition to treat the problem numerically, I have no idea how bvp4c deals with it.